# Implementing touch sounds with Qt5 Quick Controls 2

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm currently looking for a way to implement touch sounds for a Qt5 Quick Controls 2 app, comparable to touch sounds that are natively available on Android. However, so far I couldn't find a way to implement them reliably. The touch sounds should only occur when, e.g. a button was pressed but not when the user taps on random parts of the screen.

My first attempt was to scan the QML Object tree and connect to all `clicked()` signals in C++. This worked partially, but since I'm dynamically loading QML Code using a QML Loader Component I wasn't able to keep this synchronized even when I installed a filter for ChildAdded events on all objects in the tree. I also didn't catch all (sub) components with this approach because, e.g. the internally used QQuickSpinButton does not emit `clicked()` signals.

Has anybody ideas for alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to do that on the application level.

Use [`installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on your `QGuiApplication`, and then in your [`eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter), react to events of type `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` and `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` (I don't think you need to handle `QEvent::TouchBegin` and friends).

Comment: The problem I'm having with this approach is that I receive MouseButtonPress events even when the user is clicking on a non-clickable area like a Qml Pane.

Comment: Ah indeed! What behaviour do you want when a flickable or something else grabs the mouse control ? For example you have a listview with delegates, the user begins a scroll on a delegate: the delegate will get a press event but it will then be cancelled and have no release event. Should that trigger a sound ?

Comment: No that shouldn't trigger a sound. Sounds should only be triggered when the user clicks on a clickable area, e.g. I have a Listview where each delegate is a Rectangle containing a MouseArea implementing `onClicked`. Clicking such a delegate *should* trigger a sound but beginning to scroll on such a delegate should not.

The sounds are intended to provide feedback about a successful touch click on an ui element, e.g. the sound should only be triggered if the user indeed hit a button but not if he missed it.

Comment: So the sound should be emitted on released and not on pressed?

Comment: Sure that would probably be better but I don't see how that helps with the actual problem. When I filter MouseButtonRelease events I still have no way to deduce if a component was clicked or not.

Comment: you can check the `QQuickWindow::mouseGrabberItem()` on release, maybe emit a sound if it has a `clicked` signal (with `metaObject()->indexOfSignal("clicked()") != -1`)